# TypeError: (0 , _mockingoose.default) is not a function _ mockingooose

Tags: jestjs, mockingoose

I am trying to mock my mongoose schemas.with this code :

```
// report.schema.js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const reportSchema = new Schema(
  {
    data:{
        type: string
    },
  
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);
```

and inside my test:

```
import mockingoose from "mockingoose";
import Report from "../mongodb/models/report";
mockingoose(Report).toReturn({ data: "some_foo" }, "findOne");
```

and the error is:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _mockingoose.default) is not a function

      1 | import mockingoose from "mockingoose";
      2 | import Report from "../mongodb/models/report";
    > 3 | mockingoose(Report).toReturn({ data: "some_foo" }, "findOne");
```

Comment: Could you fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Error Message:

> TypeError: (0 , mockingoose_1.default) is not a function

In my case the problem was solved by changing syntax ES6 import/export to CommonJS

Before:

```
import mockingoose from "mockingoose"
```

After:

```
const mockingoose = require("mockingoose");
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved this problem :

```
var bookMock = sinon.mock(new Book({ title: 'Rayuela', author: 'Julio Cortazar' }));
var book = bookMock.object;
```

i used the this link
https://github.com/underscopeio/sinon-mongoose/blob/master/examples/promises/test.js
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could not properly solve the issue myself. I will get back to you if I can. By now, as a workaround you can use

```
// @ts-expect-error TS7016
import * as mockingoose from 'mockingoose'
```

In my project `"esModuleInterop": true,` does not work for some reason. Also I will provide you my `tsconfig.json` just in case:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["ES2021"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve"
  }
}
```

Comment: ESLint is going crazy, but the `@ts-expect-error` works for me