# mockingoose does not work with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mockingoose

The following import

```
import mockingoose from 'mockingoose';
```

gives an error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'mockingoose'.` with TypeScript.

According to this [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mockingoose),

> mockingoose provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/mockingoose installed!

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You might try hardcoding the location of the `.d.ts` file (should be in node_modules/mockingoose)  into `tsconfig.json` in the `include` array? Or try to copy the file from here: https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose/blob/master/types.d.ts

Comment: @Kokodoko Thank you, now that message disappears but I have this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156753/typeerror-0-mockingoose-default-is-not-a-function-mockingooose

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71617784/2863051
there is a workaround I posted in this answer